# How to locate a web element using webdriver:

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How can we locate the web element whose html is:

```
<div class="wgt dashlet-pane-flowing vbox h-stretch" style="flex: 8 8 0%;">
```

I have tried following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".wgt.dashlet-pane-flowing.vbox.h-stretch"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='wgt dashlet-pane-flowing vbox h-stretch']"));
```

but it is failed with error unable to locate web element.

Any help will be great..
Thanks in advance.

[image: [enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Target `div` might be generated dynamically, so you can try to wait for its appearance in `DOM`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='wgt dashlet-pane-flowing vbox h-stretch']")));
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and found this error:  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='wgt dashlet-pane-flowing vbox h-stretch']"}

Comment: ok. Try this `XPath` `//div[./div[starts-with(@id, 'pane-FlowingPos-')]]`

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[./div[starts-with(@id, 'pane-FlowingPos-0.0.0')]]"}

Comment: Hm... You can't get `NoSuchElementException` with my code. Are you sure you're using my code?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reason you will get this error.

1. Element is in different frame (which I don't think is the case)
2. It's not loaded properly while you are trying to find out (which might be the case). Please read about **explicit waits** and it will resolve the issue. I don't like giving the direct answer but someone here will. :)
3. Your xpath is wrong. You can check that with firebug and xpather plugin of firefox.
4. You have landed on the wrong page (you can check that visually)

Comment: I rechecked:1)Element is not inside frame.

Comment: 2) I have tried explicit wait until the element is visible but it fails with  error : Unable to locate element:     3)with firepath xpath: .//*@id='dashboardPreview']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div but it is also failing to locate element 4) I am at right page.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is good and still you are not able to find element, try below xpath

```
//div[contains(@style,'flex: 8 8 0%')]"
```

Comment: the given selector //div[@style,'flex: 8 8 0%;'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@style,'flex: 8 8 0%;'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Your xpath will not work here. Try this xpath = `//div[@style='flex: 8 8 0%']`  Use style attribute of `<div>` tag.

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@style='flex: 8 8 0%;']"}

Comment: try this to locate using child node

//div[@id='pane-FLowingPos-0.0.0']/..

make sure this id is not dynamic

Comment: //div[contains(@style,'flex: 8 8 0%')] make sure you are not using ; [semi-column] in xpath syntax.